# How to wipe out and fix a broken apt-get system of an old/toy machine, without re-formatting the hard drive?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'm trying to fix `apt-get` from an old toy machine so I can install packages again.

I get this after `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 avahi-daemon : Depends: upstart-job
                Depends: upstart (>= 0.6.7-4) but it is not installed
 cron : Depends: upstart-job
 dbus : Depends: upstart-job
        Depends: upstart (>= 0.6.3-6) but it is not installed
 hostname : PreDepends: upstart-job
 ifupdown : Depends: upstart-job
 initscripts : Depends: upstart but it is not installed
 module-init-tools : Depends: upstart-job
 mysql-server-5.1 : Depends: upstart-job
                    Depends: upstart (>= 0.6.7-3) but it is not installed
 netbase : Depends: upstart-job
 openssh-server : Depends: upstart-job
 plymouth : Depends: upstart-job
            Depends: mountall (>= 2.0) but it is not installed
            Recommends: plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text but it is not installed or
                        plymouth-theme
 procps : Depends: upstart-job
 rsyslog : Depends: upstart-job
 screen : Depends: upstart-job
 udev : Depends: upstart-job
 ufw : Depends: upstart-job
 ureadahead : Depends: libnih1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: upstart (>= 0.6.0) but it is not installed
 util-linux : Depends: upstart-job
 vsftpd : Depends: upstart-job
 x11-common : Depends: upstart-job
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

But when I try to install `upstart-job` I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install upstart-job
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'upstart' instead of 'upstart-job'
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 plymouth : Depends: mountall (>= 2.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text but it is not going to be installed or
                        plymouth-theme
 upstart : Depends: libnih-dbus1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libnih1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: mountall but it is not going to be installed
 ureadahead : Depends: libnih1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Update works:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Get:2 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease [110 kB]
Get:3 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease [110 kB]
Fetched 321 kB in 1s (498 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

Since this is a toy machine, I'm open to aggressive approaches/ideas besides re-formatting it.

Thanks!

Comment: Upstart was yet another attempt to do things differently to everyone else, since abandoned. You could start by installing Systemd, but you face many hurdles. You will never know if it's "perfectly fixed" - so a full re-install is going to be more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

upstart was Ubuntu's old init system, since removed and replaced by systemd. You did not specify the version of ubuntu, but it's possible it's been broken beyond repair by this point.

The ideal would have been to do a series of distro upgrades from one stable to the next until you ended up on current ubuntu impish, which I would not have tried jumping to, assuming the machine has enough resources to run current ubuntu.

It sounds to me like you tried upgrading the distribution to current ubuntu release version without actually doing the upgrade process properly, which would have resulted in the upstart to systemd conversion happening reasonably seamlessly. But that's a huge change.

You have to specify more details:

- Ubuntu version you started out with
- desktop you started with
- worst case, did the system have Mir running? or was it straight Xorg?
- what you did to create the initial apt break, that would have been either an attempt to install a newer package from newer repos, or an attempt to do an incomplete release upgrade, it looks like the latter in your case.

On Debian I'd have put your odds of success quite high, but on Ubuntu not quite as high, but probably still doable.

The key in your position is to NOT reboot until you have the full conversion completed without any lingering errors.

Because you are getting upstart conflict errors, that suggests you updated the repos without actually doing the release upgrade, which almost certainly would have had to have been done the starting LTS release to the next LTS release, NOT the current one, which is almost certain to fail if you try skipping any LTS releases.

As long as you leave the system running and do not reboot, you should be able to start poking away at the packages until you stop getting errors, then you can start rebuilding it, but if you at any point try rebooting, your odds of success will plummet.

Basically you have to convert the system to systemd from upstart, which is going to be messy, and should have been left to the ubuntu release upgrade tool.

APT can handle this scenario usually, but you have to do everything right, and the time you spend will be massively larger than a straight reinstall, and will not be nearly as clean, so the only real reason to do this is to learn command line apt tools much better than you probably know them today.

Ubuntu release upgrade tools tend to work quite well, but not if you jump lts versions, and also, they tend to only work reliably if it's LTS to next LTS upgrade, or last current point release to next point release (between LTS releases, that is, unless the next release also happens to be a LTS release).

The key is to recognize when the packages being removed are critical, and when they are going to need to be replaced manually. Sometimes if you replace them all at the same time, apt does better at figuring it out, other times, you have to do them one at at time, or combine the two methods, in order to avoid the conflicts. It's advanced apt-fu that is, takes some experience, or more likely luck in you case, usually works though if you have some idea of what you are doing and what packages will be critical to replace and which won't be.

You also need to determine which packages are replaced by other ones, which ones are no long in apt, and which have direct replacements. apt-cache search [package] is your friend there.

Expect this process to take several hours, which will lead to either success or failure, failure just means you install a new ubuntu and call it a day, success means you actually got the stuff to upgrade and cleaned up the old upstart stuff, and switched to systemd, installed the new kernel, and rebooted successfully, although possibly you would have to reinstall your desktop at that point as well, from CLI.